# Creating new column based on a condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which is called persons. It looks like this:

```
id,name,surname,status
1,name1,Garcia,parent
2,name2,Garcia,child
3,name3,Garcia,child
4,name4,Garcia,child
5,name5,Miller,parent
6,name6,Miller,child
7,name7,Miller,child
```

I want to add "childrencount" column which shows children count. If person is a child the value of "childrencount" column must be zero. I mean,

```
id,name,surname,status,childrencount
1,name1,Garcia,parent,3
2,name2,Garcia,child,0
3,name3,Garcia,child,0
4,name4,Garcia,child,0
5,name5,Miller,parent,2
6,name6,Miller,child,0
7,name7,Miller,child,0
```

I've tried:

`SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'child' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS childrencount FROM persons GROUP BY surname;`

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `case` expression inside `sum()`:

```
select *,
case
when status = 'child' then 0
else sum(case when status = 'child' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by surname)
end as childrencount
from table_name;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=68f24183cf1f13f3473667e95db24ea0)

Comment: thank you and your fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUM()` window function inside a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE status
         WHEN 'child' THEN 0
         WHEN 'parent' THEN SUM((status = 'child')::int) OVER (PARTITION BY surname) 
       END AS childrencount 
FROM persons;
```